Can't "test" amazon alexa custom skill in the developer console
I'm trying to develop a simple notification custom skill served on a web service using "django-ask-sdk".
On the "build" tab, all the "Building Your Skill" categories are green:

Invocation Name: OK
Intents, Samples, and Slots: OK
Build Model: OK
Endpoint: OK

On the "test" tab, "skill testing is enabled in" is set to "Development".
On the "test" tab, in the "Alexa Simulator", it appears that I can issue a request, but the response is, "The requested skill can't be accessed".
I'm using "HTTPS" endpoint type, and the endpoint set for the "Default Region" is correct.
I'm not seeing any request being sent to my endpoint.
Am I missing some configuration, or am I not understanding how the test tab works?
How can I get a test request sent to my web skill?
